# Тернарный оператор в шаблонах

Tags: php

Буду краток, создаю шаблон для нескольких контроллеров, и хочу избежать множества конструкций вида:

```
if (isset && !empty) echo...;
```

Найденный выход:

```
echo ($text)?:'';
```

Но все говорят мне, что решение не самое эффективное. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как сделать лучше?

Comment: Пожалуйста, переведите вопрос на русский язык и впредь используете только его. Это русскоязычный сайт и другие языки здесь не приветствуются.

Comment: Ой, простите меня, пожалуйста. Постараюсь быть внимательней.
Интерфейсы сайтов практически одинаковы, а я привык к обоим языкам.  Спасибо за ваше замечание.

Comment: Хотя вы знаете... Я специально выбирал англоязычную часть сайта для поста вопроса... 
Но там у меня смешанные сообщения. Как быть уверенным, что я пишу в англоязычный сайт? Посмотрите, пожалуйста, скриншот. http://puu.sh/hVwuc/502d77a89d.png

Comment: Русский SO имеет адрес  **ru**.stackoverlfow.com, кроме того, на картинке тоже написано, что сайт на русском: http://screencast.com/t/aafNDPv9E

Comment: А сообщения в inbox и уведомление о репутации падают со всех сайтов сети StackExchange, куда входят оба SO и ещё очень много разных сайтов.

Answer (score 1):

Оба варианта плохи.

1. Во-первых, условие (isset && !empty) само по себе не имеет смысла, вместо него надо писать (!empty).
2. Во-вторых, непонятно, зачем проверять переменную на существование. Контроллер как бы обязан определить все переменные для вывода.
3. В-третьих, непонятно, зачем проверять переменную на пустоту? Почему бы не написать просто `echo $text;`?
4. В-четвертых, за вывод вообще должен отвечать шаблонизатор с автоискейпингом.

Но если отвлечься от шаблонизатора, и говорить о проверках вообще, то

- `if (isset($var))` если переменная может быть не определена
- `if (!empty($var))` если переменная не пустая и может быть не определена
- `if ($var)` если переменная не пустая

а употреблять ли тернарный оператор или нет - дело вкуса.

Comment: Простите, коллега, в этой строчке все верно?

if (!isset($var)) если переменная не пустая и может быть не определена

Comment: if (!isset($var)): "если переменная НЕ задана или задана, но пустая (т.е. равна null)"

Answer (score 0):

Ваши мотивы понятны, но вы выбрали не самой удачный способ.

```
echo ($text)?:'';
```

Это выражение будет порождать предупреждение "Переменная не задана", если задан соответствующий [уровень вывода ошибок](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.error-reporting.php).
Если поискать хорошие примеры, то можно найти такой способ: шаблонизатор Laravel Blade транслирует вот такую  конструкцию:

```
{{ $name or 'Default' }}
```

в выражение

```
echo isset($name) ? $name : 'Default';
```

Видите разницу? [isset](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.isset.php) страхует вас от выдачи предупреждения и при этом почти не добавляет тормозов, т.к. это не функция, а конструкция языка.
По сравнению с этим !empty() отбросил бы еще варианты $name===0 и $name==='0', это было бы слишком хорошо :)

Comment: Большое спасибо! Теперь полностью понятно.